# How can I make the input search bar, microphone image and two small boxes responsive?

Tags: html, css

After submitting my exercise for The Odin Project. I had thought that everything was aligned and centered when viewed on my MacBook Pro 15inch. But when I looked at the completed webpage at work on a bigger computer screen, I noticed that the input search box wasn't centered anymore. Along with that, the microphone image that sits inside of the search box and the two grey buttons below it are floating into space when the window is resized.

Instead of re-writing the exercise over. I tried to place the form box, the microphone image and the two buttons inside their own Divs to see if that would help with centering the box, but no luck. I've also played around with flexbox, margin: 0 auto, and setting the widths differently, but nothing.

You can check it out here:
https://lawsin-google-homepage.netlify.com/

Code for the project is here:
https://repl.it/@jl88s/RoyalblueFarTrust

```
<section class="main-container">

        <h1 class="google-logo-header">Google</h1>
        <img src="google-logo.svg" alt="google-logo" id="google-logo">

        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <input class="form-box" type="text" name="search">
            <a href="#"><img src="google-mic.png" id="google-mic" alt="microphone"></a>
        </form>

        <button class="btn-one buttons">Google Search</button>
        <button class="btn-two buttons">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>

</section>
```

What I expect is whenever I resize the window, I would like for the search box, mic, and the buttons to be centered and responsive to the size of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Here I leave a demo that can help you:

---

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
            <input class="form-box" type="text" name="search">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://police.un.org/sites/default/files/radio-microphone.png" id="google-mic" alt="microphone"></a>
        </form>
```

---

```
    form{
    position:relative;
}
input{
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin:0;
}
a{
    margin:0;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    position:relative;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
}
a img{
    width: 30px;
    margin:2px 10px;
}
```

---

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPzMyv

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to adjust the styles, try to replace your style.css file with this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 100vh;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.header-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

.nav-list ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-list ul li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-half {
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.left-half li a{
    margin: 15px 8.5px 0 10px;
}

.right-half {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.dot-box {
    padding: 0 3px;
}

.dots {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    opacity: .7;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.dots:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.sign-in-btn {
    padding-right: 22px;
}

#sign-in-button {
     color: #fff;
     border: 1px solid #4285f4;
     font-weight: bold;
     background:#4387fd;
     line-height: 28px;
     padding: 0 12px;
     border-radius: 2px;
     opacity: 1;
     text-decoration: none;
}

/* #02. Title / Search Bar */

.google-logo-header {
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999999px;
}

#google-logo {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 370px;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: .91;
}

.main-container {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.form-box {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 
    0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
    width: 584px;
    height: 44px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;

    font-size: medium;
    padding-left: 16px;
}

.form-box:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 
    0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
}

#google-mic {
    position: relative;
    right: 38px;
    height: 20px;
}

.buttons {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #757575;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 11px 4px;
    min-width: 54px;
    padding: 9px 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

.buttons:hover {
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    color: #000;
}

.btn-one {
    position: relative;

}
input{

}
.btn-two {
    position: relative;

}

/* #03. Footer */

.footer-container {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.footer-list {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.footer-list li a {
    padding-left: 27px;
}

.settings-pad {
    padding-right: 27px;
}

.footer-right {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue with making your site responsive is that you are using lots of `position: absolute;` and setting exact left and right positions. This is generally really bad if you want to make a responsive site. The best way to accomplish this is by using Flexbox or CSS Grid and Media Queries, all come with stock standard CSS.

Here is some reading if you want to learn more

Flexbox:

- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)
- [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

CSS Grid:

- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)
- [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Media Queries:

- [Responsive Web Design - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
- [CSS Media Queries Examples - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

### Changes to your code

Here are the changes that I made to your code. Your HTML is fine, I just slightly changed it to allow for the use of Flexbox.

```
<section class="main-container">
    <!-- <h1 class="google-logo-header">Google</h1> -->
    <img src="images/google-logo.svg" alt="google-logo" id="google-logo">
    <form class="search-bar" action="/action_page.php">
        <input class="form-box" type="text" name="search">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/google-mic.png" id="google-mic" alt="microphone"></a>
    </form>
    <div class="btn-row">
        <button class="btn-one buttons">Google Search</button>
        <button class="btn-two buttons">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

For your CSS, I changed the `.main-container` to be a flexbox column with all items aligned to the vertical center

```
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center
}
```

I also removed `position: absolute` and left, right, bottom, top rules from all of the elements as they used set px amounts and was not responsive as a result.

The `.search-bar` class that I added to your form was to simply make if a flexbox row which would also align items to the vertical center.

```
.search-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

#google-mic {
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Due to the mic image always being right after the input box, you can then set a set negative margin-left to it which will make it shift to the left. This may not be the best way to do this however I have not found issues with this in the past.

Just as will the `.search-bar` I simply added in a div with the class `btn-row` and wrapped your two buttons inside of it to allow them to be in a flexbox row.

```
.btn-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1b38zhwc/) for the working example, keep in mind that I did not change things like the set px widths on the input box which will cause issues on mobile screens etc.

I would recommend looking into the resources I linked, and trying to use % widths for things like the search bar. You will also need to change the svg that you have so that there is not so much whitespace above and below the actual Google logo. I tried setting a height on the image but that just shrunk the whole thing.